# Is it possible to reuse an HTTP Request Body multiple times without reading it into memory?

Tags: java, go, rust, file-upload, checksum

My requirement is a large file upload, using `curl -T <file>`, the server side is an HTTP Server in Rust, the implementation can be `actix-web` (or `hyper` if other implementations are more suitable), using `HTTP/1.1`. In `HTTP/1.1`, the server can only read the file upload data stream once, and I want to calculate the file's `MD5`, `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` (or `BLAKE3`) without reading the file data stream into memory, and then upload it to S3. If there is a solution for parallel calculation, it will be better, but it may be more complex, the key is still to reuse the stream.

It is best not to use a `channel` to implement it, as the stream will flow through multiple `channel` to calculate the Checksum, which may have a lower performance than reusing the stream to calculate at the same time.

This needs to be based on the Rust 2021 Edition, `actix-web` 4.x version (the latest is 4.3.0), and if `tokio` is used, it must be at least 1.0.0+ (I am currently 1.25.0). This is because the compatibility of library versions in Rust is too poor, and there may be API incompatibilities between each minor version.

May I ask if my requirement can be implemented using Rust? In Go, it seems that there is no better solution besides `io.Pipe`, but the performance of `io.Pipe` does not look good.

Thank you very much for your advice and patience!

---

Update: You can use either Go or Java for this requirement.

Comment: This question is currently too broad, I'm afraid. At the very least, what are the methods for hashing/uploading you're using? Depending on what their API requires, this might either be possible (with the bytes manually pulled from the stream and copied into a couple of sinks) or not.

Comment: So the goal is to read a stream progressively, say 1KB at a time, and pipe that 1KB into three other readers that will produce the hashes?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, the goal can be understood as having two main points: first, to avoid reading or caching the file in memory, which would result in an OOM error; and second, to reuse the stream, as it will be used multiple times to calculate.

Comment: @Cerberus I have slightly modified the description, defining the upload method as using `curl -T 5G.txt` to upload the file, and the server side is an HTTP Server implemented in Rust, which could be actix-web or hyper.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as doing calculations without putting the file in memory, at least on standard hardware. The solution is reading it in chunks with an implementer of [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html), such as [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html).

This is fully possible in synchronous rust, but since you specified tokio, I made this async, using tokio's IO types and traits. You can make the same thing synchronously with the standard library's IO types and traits, which are named similarly.

First, a function that takes a reader, updates a slice of hash functions, and then writes those bytes to a writer. This is essentially [`tokio::io::copy_buf`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.25.0/tokio/io/fn.copy_buf.html) but with hash functions in the middle.

```rs
pub async fn calculate_hashes<R, W>(
    mut reader: R,
    hashers: &mut [&mut dyn Update],
    mut writer: W,
) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
where
    R: AsyncBufRead + Unpin,
    W: AsyncWrite + Unpin,
{
    loop {
        let part = reader.fill_buf().await?;
        if part.is_empty() {
            break;
        }

        for hasher in hashers.iter_mut() {
            hasher.update(part);
        }

        writer.write_all(part).await?;

        let part_len = part.len();
        reader.consume(part_len);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This uses a trait from the [digest](https://docs.rs/digest/0.10.5/digest/index.html) crate: [`Update`](https://docs.rs/digest/0.10.5/digest/trait.Update.html). Luckily, there's already implementations of your specific hash functions that use digest: [md-5](https://docs.rs/md-5/0.10.5/md5/index.html), [sha1](https://docs.rs/sha1/0.10.5/sha1/index.html), and [sha2](https://docs.rs/sha2/0.10.5/sha2/index.html) (make sure you use versions that depend on the same version of digest, which conveniently are all 0.10.5 at the moment).

Here's that function in use:

```rs
pub async fn md5_sha1_sha256<R, W>(
    reader: R,
    writer: W,
) -> Result<(Md5, Sha1, Sha256), std::io::Error>
where
    R: AsyncBufRead + Unpin,
    W: AsyncWrite + Unpin,
{
    let mut md5_hasher = Md5::new();
    let mut sha1_hasher = Sha1::new();
    let mut sha256_hasher = Sha256::new();

    calculate_hashes(
        reader,
        &mut [&mut md5_hasher, &mut sha1_hasher, &mut sha256_hasher],
        writer,
    )
    .await?;

    Ok((md5_hasher, sha1_hasher, sha256_hasher))
}
```

If you want to go further, you could make a wrapper type that implements `AsyncWrite` for all `Update` types, and then you wouldn't even need to separate `hashers` and `writer`. You could also go the other way and split `hashers` into your specific hash function types or a specific number of generic arguments, which avoids `dyn`. I used a `dyn` slice here so that it is helpful to others in less specific situations.

[Here's a link to the whole thing on playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d05693b933ef05eb923d354a00f3a0a3) It doesn't compile because of missing dependencies, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help. I understand your idea roughly, but it is slightly different from my real situation. I apologize for my insufficient understanding of Rust. My actual situation is to use `curl -T <FILE>` to upload a file to a rust http server, the HTTP request body is used to calculate MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256 at the same time. Then, it will check if there are any references to the same checksum in the database, and decide whether to upload the body to S3 or just return it.

Comment: The response will write these values in the form of JSON into the response body.

Comment: One more question, for the buffer form you just mentioned, the file data will not be read into memory or buffer, right? I am worried that uploading large files will cause OOM.

Comment: The buffer is limited (you can decide the capacity manually) and will store up to the limit from the reader.

The thing you're trying to do sounds fully impossible. It would be possible to 1. upload and delete it if it's a duplicate, or 2. check the hash and then curl the file again to upload it, or 3. save it to disk and then upload it. But you can't conditionally upload it after you've read the entire thing.

If it's just for deduplication, check the first few bytes and the length, and then use #1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation idea in Go: Calculate the Checksum of the Request Body while writing it to the S3 storage.

```golang
// ...

md5Hasher := md5.New()
sha1Hasher := sha1.New()
sha256Hasher := sha256.New()

type Checksum struct {
    Md5    string `json:"md5"`
    Sha1   string `json:"sha1"`
    Sha256 string `json:"sha256"`
}

hasher := io.MultiWriter(md5Hasher, sha1Hasher, sha256Hasher)
tr := io.TeeReader(r.Body, hasher)

// Upload the file to S3.
_, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("key"),
    Body:   tr,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("failed to upload file, %v", err)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

checksum := Checksum{
    Md5:    fmt.Sprintf("%x", md5Hasher.Sum(nil)),
    Sha1:   fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha1Hasher.Sum(nil)),
    Sha256: fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256Hasher.Sum(nil)),
}

respBody, _ := json.MarshalIndent(checksum, "", "  ")
fmt.Printf("%s\n", respBody)

w.Write(respBody)
```

But now I am thinking, can I calculate the Checksum first through `io.MultiWriter` and then decide whether to upload the Request Body. But at this point, it seems there is no good way to use a Request Body that has already been read as an upload logic without reading it into memory or writing it to a temporary file.